# How to force Wordpress to add new images at the beginning of the gallery?

Tags: images, gallery

I have the standard gallery embedded in the page and want to add new images to it. When I select images and click `Add to gallery` button Wordpress adds them at the end. 
How to force it to add images at the beginning (top)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just fixed this after several hours of research.
If one need to do the same thing, he must edit file `wp-includes\js\media-views.js` and replace `add` with `unshift` in this line (#2611, galleryAddToolbar):

```
edit.get('library').add( state.get('selection').models );
```

So the code will look like this:

```
edit.get('library').unshift( state.get('selection').models );
```

After that when you add images in the gallery they will appear at the top.