# Add new images to top of existing gallery not bottom

Tags: gallery

I have existing wordpress gallery. When I add new images to it, they are added at the bottom of gallery automatically but I would like to have them at the top as first images in gallery. Of course I can drag and drop them to the top manually but if you have a large gallery and add about 30 new images it is not easy.

Comment: I tried solution posted on this question( http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/157118/how-to-force-wordpress-to-add-new-images-at-the-beginning-of-the-gallery) but it did'n work for me.

Comment: I mean what work have you done yourself? What code have you written and tested to try and fix this issue? Its a good question but you must work on it yourself and then ask for help when your solution doesn't work as per the guidelines http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help

Comment: The thing is that I have made my own website and came across this problem stated in my question above. I have not written any code to fix this issue because I am not so advanced and don't know where should start or what code should I write. So if you asking what I have done myself, its 2 days research online with no luck, tried solution writen here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/157118/how-to-force-wordpress-to-add-new-images-at-the-beginning-of-the-gallery with no luck and I am stuck right no. And that is why I asked for help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a version of the linked solution that overrides `galleryAddToolbar` to have an extra button (`insertTop`) to do what you want (in your "functions.php"):

```
add_filter( 'media_view_strings', function ( $strings, $post ) {
    $strings['addToGallery'] = __( 'Add to end of gallery' );
    $strings['addToGalleryTop'] = __( 'Add to start of gallery' );
    return $strings;
}, 10, 2 );

add_action( 'admin_footer' , function () {
    ?>
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        (function ($) {
            if (typeof wp.media !== 'undefined') {
                wp.media.view.MediaFrame.Post.prototype.galleryAddToolbar = function () {
                    var media = wp.media, l10n = media.view.l10n;
                    this.toolbar.set( new media.view.Toolbar({
                        controller: this,
                        items: {
                            insert: {
                                style:    'secondary',
                                text:     l10n.addToGallery,
                                priority: 70,
                                requires: { selection: true },

                                /**
                                 * @fires wp.media.controller.State#reset
                                 */
                                click: function() {
                                    var controller = this.controller,
                                        state = controller.state(),
                                        edit = controller.state('gallery-edit');

                                    edit.get('library').add( state.get('selection').models );
                                    state.trigger('reset');
                                    controller.setState('gallery-edit');
                                }
                            },
                            insertTop: {
                                style:    'primary',
                                text:     l10n.addToGalleryTop,
                                priority: 80,
                                requires: { selection: true },

                                /**
                                 * @fires wp.media.controller.State#reset
                                 */
                                click: function() {
                                    var controller = this.controller,
                                        state = controller.state(),
                                        edit = controller.state('gallery-edit');

                                    edit.get('library').unshift( state.get('selection').models );
                                    state.trigger('reset');
                                    controller.setState('gallery-edit');
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }) );
                };
            }
        })(jQuery);
    });
    </script>
    <?php
} );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for solution! You saved my day!!! Works perfectly!!!

Answer (score 0):

This helped me on a client project SO MUCH! But with the Wordpress 4.4 update, the "Add to Start of Gallery" button disappeared.

I found that the div the buttons go into was changed to 33% width after the update. You can change the width to 100% and the button will reappear. The class is "**.media-modal-content .media-toolbar-primary.search-form**" in the **media-views-rtl.min.cs**s which can be found in wp-includes>css

I hope this helps others who found the fix to be valuable.